# Display a calculated Timestamp when a particular choice is selected (Sharepoint list)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column

I would like to create a calculated column that displays the timestamp (mm/dd/yyyy) when a choice was picked from another column. The column in question is named Assessment Status and the choice that needs the timestamp is Ready for Review.

P.S.
No infopath or 3rd party apps, just need the calculated formula

Comment: Yes that is true, I would be creating the timestamp when the status is changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carl,
Try this formula.

=IF(Status="Ready to Review",TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mm"),IF(ISBLANK(Status),"","NULL"))

It works in my online list properly.

Update:
It will update the timestamp every time it is edited when the status is ready to review. So if it will be a potential issue, i will recommend you to use a very simple workflow with SharePoint Designer to get this work done. Please let me know if that could be you option. It is out of box and very easy to use/maintain.

Comment: Wouldn't that update the field every time the item is saved and 'Status="Ready to Review"'?

Comment: @MortenK  Yes, as you said, it will update the timestamp. Thanks for pointing out this. Per my knowledge, this is kind of the limit of a calculated formula for it does not store values. I guess the best OOB way is still using workflow. Any other ideas?

Comment: I would do it using a workflow and a second choice field to keep track if the status has changed or not and then simply update a normal date field. I agree calculated fields aren't of much use in this case :)

Comment: Hi the formula you posted doesn't work (wrong formula). So I played around with it and the forumla that has been accepted was this =IF([Assessment Status]="Ready to Review",TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"),IF(ISBLANK([Assessment Status]),"","NULL")). However, it does not display the date when the status is changed. P.S. The column's name is Assessment Status.

Comment: It only stays as "NULL"

Comment: @CarlCham I tested with your formula in my environment and it works properly. Is the Status column a choice column or anything else?

Comment: My apologies, it was just an error, instead of Ready for Review it was Ready to Review, but essentially the formula that I have reposted works. Thanks for the help!